# removing iterating element from list

Tags: python-3.x, list

i was trying sorting list without sort function in python and got it right. here is the code:

```
list1=[2,7,8,23,1,56,4,8,0]
new_list=[]

while list1:
    min = list1[0]  
    for x in list1:
        if x < min:
            min = x
    new_list.append(min) 
    list1.remove(min) 
print(new_list)
```

and its working properly.

but out of curiousity to check e what happens, i changed **list1.remove(min) to list1.remove(x)**
and i am getting following output as list.

[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

can someone explain me why i am getting these 0,1,2 as output?

Comment: because removing an element from a list causes every index to shift backwards, if you do it while iterating, it will skip the next element

Comment: FYI, it is recommended not to use ```min``` as the variable name as this is a python builtin module. You can check the builtin module names with ```print(dir(builtins))```